# Spring Data Elasticsearch wildcard query with sort

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I wrote a search query for elasticsearch:

```
{
"query": {
    "query_string": {
        "fields": ["studentName", "countryName"],
        "query" : "*o*"
    }
  },
"sort" : [{ 
    "studentName" : { "order": "desc" }
  }]
}
```

This is executed for `localhost:9200/myindex/mytype/_search` (POST).

I get correct results based on the `query` which are sorted on the basis of `sort` part. But when I convert this into Spring Data Query like:

```
@Query("{ \"query\": { \"query_string\" : { \"fields\" : [\"studentName\", \"countryName\"], \"query\":\"*?0*\"}}," +
        " \"sort\" : [{ \"?1\" : { \"order\": \"?2\" }}]}")
Page<Student> freeTextSearchPortSort(String freeText, String sortBy, String sortOrder, Pageable pageable);
```

I always get the same result, sorted on the order of insertion. What do I need to do differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create  [PageRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#PageRequest-int-int-org.springframework.data.domain.Sort.Direction-java.lang.String...-) which has a constructor that takes page,size ,direction,properties. PageRequest implements `Pageable` interface.

Your query would look like:

```
@Query("{ \"query\": { \"query_string\" : { \"fields\" : [\"studentName\", \"countryName\"], \"query\":\"*?0*\"}}")
Page<Student> freeTextSearchPortSort(String freeText, Pageable pageable);
```

The location from where this is being called will look like.

```
PageRequest pageRequest = new PageRequest(0, no_of_rec_to_be_fetched, Sort.Direction.fromString("desc"), "studentName")

freeTextSearchPortSort ("someText",pageRequest)
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: This was the mistake I was doing. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I just noticed that the query isn't able to sort a mix of text and numbers. In some of my inputs, I have chars like `-`, and `(`. Can they be managed?